# Facebook public search returns more results than api or fql...what gives?

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

If I try FQL versions of the above, I get the same results.

If you do a search in the main facebook website for "Mustang Brewing Company", it returns the page (http://www.facebook.com/mustangbrewingcompany)...no problem...

However, if I try to find it in FQL or the graph api, it never finds it...Doesn't matter if I do a place, page, distance , center changes, user etc... search I am never able to find it through the API...I've tried every indexable field in the user, page, place and profile tables. Go to facebook.com and enter "Mustang Brewing Company" in searchbox top center.

The result list will return Mustang Brewing Company which is correct.

If I try: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Mustang+Brewing+Company&type=page&access_token=xxx Returns 2 results, but neither is the page the facebook search finds

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DMustang Brewing Company&type=page&access_token=xxxx Returns 0 result

Comment: Why the negative number?

Comment: Probably since you didn't search and research this question.  It's been asked many times on Stackoverflow.  I know I've answered the same question at least twice.  On stackoverflow they like one question on the entire site (they like to think of the site as a wiki where there's one entry per subject like on wikipedia).

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB missing search results - fb site search versus API\FQL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9542352/fb-missing-search-results-fb-site-search-versus-api-fql)

Comment: Noted and thanks...That was a repost of an existing question...For that, I understand...I'm just desperate to figure this out...

The problem is I did search extensively (here and internet wide), created a FB bug report and searched even more...I can find no definitive answer on this or noone knows the answer...Perhaps I'm not asking the question right or searching for the right results which is why I didn't run across your previous answers (in regards to the research the answer)...

Answer (score 0):

I think your search string is wrong.

Try:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Mustang Brewing Company&type=page&access_token=...`.

Comment: What makes you think it was me?

Comment: Alexander...My bad...This my first time to really use this system...Just trying to get my bearings...Thanks though...